# How to create a matrix using a 2D array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a 6x3 matrix that increases by one each time as you iterate over the column first and the row second.

This is the code, which I currently have:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {

    int[][] mat1 = new int[6][3];
    for(int i = 1; i < mat1.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat1[i].length; j++) {
            mat1[i][j] = i + j;
            System.out.print(mat1[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Right now I am getting the output:

```
1 2 3 
2 3 4 
3 4 5 
4 5 6 
5 6 7
```

The desired output is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why doesn't  the outer loop start at `int i = 0` ? Your output is currently missing a row.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. And: a really nice question here. All details, expected input output, excellent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *want* to generate a "sequence" that counts from 0, 1, 2, .. 17. 
Your problem is that `i+j` doesn't generate that sequence.

Therefore:

```
mat1[i][j] = i + j;
```

is simply **not** counting up. A much simpler solution would be this:

```
mat1[i][j] = overallCounter++;
```

( and that `overallCounter` is declared `int overallCounter = 0` **before** the outer for loop ).

**side note**: and as the comment correctly states: i should start at 0, too. Arrays are 0-based in Java!

Comment: @R.Lee The overallcounter is the best solution here. If you have doubts with calculations in loops, then write down the steps on paper to understand them. Yours would be like `1+0 1+1 1+2; 2+0 2+1 2+2; 3+0 3+1 3+2; ....`

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. @GameDroids thank you for the great advice. I will make sure to do that.

Comment: And just for the record: that overall counter also tells you how you can *map* a NxM twodim array as 1 dim array. Meaning: in the end, having one index going from 0 to 17 ... is "the same" has having two indexes 3 x 6 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The output you get is correct:

```
On the first iteration, i = 1 and j = 0, so i+j = 1
On the 4th iteration i = 2 and j = 0, so i+j = 2
On the 7th iteration i = 3 and j = 0, so i+j = 3
```

here is on of the solution for your problem

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {

  int[][] mat1 = new int[6][3];
  int counter = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < mat1.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat1[i].length; j++) {
            mat1[i][j] = counter;
            counter++;
            System.out.print(mat1[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```